# change <li> background color after 3 secs without javascript

Tags: html, css

How do I change the background color of a `<li>` element after 3 seconds the page is loaded without any javascript or JQuery? Only with CSS? I've seen people doing amazing things with CSS only and I think that this is also very possible.

This `<li>` is performing a horizontal menu and i would like to highlight this option for the 3 first seconds after the page is loaded.

No problem if the solution is css3 and HTML5.

Comment: Shouldn't you give a reason why you mark something down? That way, at least the author learns something... and the rest of us.

Comment: Pabluez, I don't think this is possible without some javascript to manage the timing following onload. Not sure what HTML5 offers but I doubt it offers something this specific. Jquery is really a development paradigm and library based on javascript.

Comment: Thank you @wmorrison365 , I think the same way as you. There's no reason for the down votes, the question is clear and if I am asking is because I thought that it would be really possible. As I'm not aware of HTML5 and CSS3 development, I'm asking this. Big shame to be treated like this. Thank you for your insight, i will wait to see if anyone can answer that, if not I will just write a very simple JS and that's it.

Comment: Might be worth checking out the W3C's CSS tutorials. They're very good and you can whizz through them quite quickly. Check them out at: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This can be done check my answer below...

Comment: I upvoted to offset this madness.

Comment: Upvoted as it seems to have at least prompted discussion - and provided some answers. Guess the mozilla solution is browser-dependent with a view to being adopted by W3C further down the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sample will do an animation on load that will change the background color of the square from red to yellow over with a transition of 5 seconds and will start 5 seconds after load - will execute only once and stay on yellow background:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        .square {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            background:red;
            position:relative;
            -moz-animation-name:colorChange;
            -moz-animation-duration:5s;
            -moz-animation-delay:5s;
            -moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
            -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
        }
        @-moz-keyframes colorChange {
            from {background:red;}
            to {background:yellow;}        
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="square"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/c8DDP/

Works from Firefox 4.0+ - the same can be accomplished using `-webkit` prefix for webkit based browsers.

Comment: genial! That's what i was looking for! Thank you so much, i will try it and will report it ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with coverage all the way down to Netscape Navigator 2.0:

**Use an animated gif as the background image**.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/VPHEX/

Comment: No, animated gifs don't have to loop.

Comment: Fair enough - didn't know you could set how many times a gif loops. Nice.